# How to remove duplicate strings that have additional words and symbols?

Tags: r, stringr

Is there a method that can remove similar duplicated words from a comma separated string? There are a few methods out there but they seem to remove exact words only.

For example the following comma separated string is given below

`words <- c("Hello, Hello, At desk (Idle), At desk (Idle)†, On floor (Active), On floor (Active)†, In meeting (Advisors), In meeting (Advisors)†, Day off (Birthday), Day off (Birthday)†")`

and the desired result is

`"Hello, At desk (Idle), On floor (Active), In meeting (Advisors), Day off (Birthday)"`

What's been tried is

`new.words <- strsplit(words, ",")`
`sapply(dup_words, function(x) rle(x)$value)`

which only removes the exact duplicated words and returns

`"Hello, At desk (Idle), At desk (Idle)†, On floor (Active), On floor (Active)†, In meeting (Advisors), In meeting (Advisors)*, Day off (Birthday), Day off (Birthday)†"`

only removing the duplicated Hello.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% what you want, since the commas will disappear, butmybe it might help you

```
library(stringr)

words <- c("Hello, Hello, At desk, At desk (Idle), On floor, On floor (Active), In meeting, In meeting *, Day off, Day off †")

words %>%
  str_split(pattern = " ",simplify = TRUE) %>%
  str_split(pattern = ",",simplify = TRUE) %>% 
  as.vector() %>%
  unique() %>%
  str_c(collapse = " ")

[1] "Hello At desk (Idle) On floor (Active) In meeting * Day off † "
```

Comment: Thank you! This is close but not quite what is being looked for. I will update the original question to make it more clear.

Comment: The original question has been updated to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the updated data and expected

```
gsub("†", "", gsub("\\([^\\)]\\)\\s*", "",
    gsub("([^,]+)(?:,\\s*\\1)*", "\\1", words)))
```

-output

```
[1] "Hello, At desk (Idle), On floor (Active), 
   In meeting (Advisors), Day off (Birthday)"
```